# Why does the monitor solution to dining-philosopher have no deadlock but starvation?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, synchronization, monitor, livelock

From Operating System Concepts

> **5.8.2 Dining-Philosophers Solution Using Monitors**
>
> Next, we illustrate monitor concepts by presenting a deadlock-free
>   solution to the dining-philosophers problem. This solution imposes the
>   restriction that a philosopher may pick up her chopsticks only if both
>   of them are available. To code this solution, we need to distinguish
>   among three states in which we may ﬁnd a philosopher. For this
>   purpose, we introduce the following data structure:
>
> ```
> enum {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING} state[5];
> ```
>
> Philosopher i can set the variable `state[i] = EATING` only if her two
>   neighbors are not eating: `(state[(i+4) % 5] != EATING)` and
>   `(state[(i+1) % 5] != EATING)`.
>
> We also need to declare
>
> ```
> condition self[5];
> ```
>
> This allows philosopher i to delay herself when she is hungry but is
>   unable to obtain the chopsticks she needs.
>
> ```
> monitor DiningPhilosophers
> {
>
>     enum {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING} state[5];
>     condition self[5];
>     void pickup(int i) {
>
>         state[i] = HUNGRY;
>         test(i);
>         if (state[i] != EATING)
>             self[i].wait();
>
>     }
>     void putdown(int i) {
>
>         state[i] = THINKING;
>         test((i + 4) % 5);
>         test((i + 1) % 5);
>
>     }
>     void test(int i) {
>
>         if ((state[(i + 4) % 5] != EATING) &&
>         (state[i] == HUNGRY) &&
>         (state[(i + 1) % 5] != EATING)) {
>             state[i] = EATING;
>             self[i].signal();
>         }
>
>     }
>     initialization code() {
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
>             state[i] = THINKING;
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Figure 5.18 A monitor solution to the dining-philosopher problem.
>
> Each philosopher, before starting to eat, must invoke the operation
>   `pickup()`. This act may result in the suspension of the philosopher
>   process. After the successful completion of the operation, the
>   philosopher may eat. Following this, the philosopher invokes the
>   `putdown()` operation.
>
> ```
> DiningPhilosophers.pickup(i);
> ...
> eat
> ...
> DiningPhilosophers.putdown(i);
> ```
>
> It is easy to show that this solution ensures that no two neighbors
>   are eating simultaneously and **that no deadlocks will occur**.
>
> We note, however, that **it is possible for a philosopher to starve to
>   death**. We do not present a **solution to this problem** but rather
>   leave it as an exercise for you.

Why does the monitor solution have no deadlock?

Why is it possible for a philosopher to starve to death?

What is a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: deadlock is a result of incorrect synchronization. How is synchronization expressed in the given code? What is the programming language used?

Answer (score 3):

To understand why two neighbours can never be eating at the same time have a look at the `test(int i)` method. This is the only place where a philosopher's state is set to `EATING`:

```
if ((state[(i + 4) % 5] != EATING) &&
    (state[i] == HUNGRY) &&
    (state[(i + 1) % 5] != EATING)) {
        state[i] = EATING;
        self[i].signal();
}
```

The preceding if condition ensures that for any philosopher `i` neither of its neighbours `(i + 4) % 5` nor `(i + 1) % 5` is eating.

Starvation is possible because [signal()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal()) is not fair: it wakes up any of the waiting threads at random and might thus not wake up a certain thread for an arbitrary long time.

Comment: Thanks. The link for Java's `signal()` doesn't say it choose a waiting thread randomly. Or do I miss something? The book introduces the general concepts not limited to Java, is `signal` generally implemented as choosing a random waiting thread? Can the waiting threads be placed in a FIFO queue?

Comment: The book also provides implementation of monitor in terms of semaphore (https://stackoverflow.com/q/46919797/156458). The book also mentions that waiting threads on a semaphore can be implemented in FIFO, so I think FIFO is the same for monitor, correct?

Comment: The Javadoc for `signal` says "If any threads are waiting on this condition then one is selected for waking up." It doesn't say which so you cannot assume anything. Moreover the class comment says "Condition factors out the Object monitor methods (wait, notify and notifyAll)" and the Javadoc for `notify` explicitly states "If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation."

Comment: Thanks. Any reason not using FIFO?

Comment: Is it possible to make it fair?

Comment: To make the solution fair you have to use explicit locking with a fair lock instead of relying on implicit object monitors. E.g. use [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock(boolean)) and [newCondition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#newCondition())