# Monitor solution of dinning philosipher

Tags: synchronization, deadlock

[Why does the monitor solution to dining-philosopher have no deadlock but starvation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46881815/17764286)

In the description of the above link,
we call pickup whenever trying to eat, and the pickup function will call test to observe left and right neighbor to decide if we could start eating.

But monitor is an ADT that only allows one active thread at a time, which means if I can execute the pickup function, I'll be the only active thread in the monitor.

Then why need I check the other two philosiphers' states? Don't they neccessarily be thinking?